# Why is DATENAME(GETDATE()) giving a different result as DATENAME(2019-02-01) when that is the date today?

Tags: sql-server, date, getdate, datepart

I don't understand why DATENAME(GETDATE()) gives a different result from DATENAME(2019-02-01) When that is today's date

```
SELECT GETDATE(), DATENAME(w, GETDATE()),DATENAME(dw, 2019-02-01)
```

Returns:

```
2019-02-01 14:51:46.017 Friday  Monday<br>
```

While I would expect it to return:

```
2019-02-01 14:51:46.017 Friday  Firday
```

Comment: hint, do a `SELECT 2019-02-01` and see what it returns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 reasons. Firstly, you're using the value `2019-02-01`; which is the expression is "2019 minus 2 minus 1"; which evaluates to `2016`. `2016` as a `datetime` is the date `'1905-07-10'` (which is 2,016th day after `'1900-01-01'`). If you get the value of `WEEKDAY` using the function `DATENAME` of `'1905-07-10'` you get `'Monday'`.

If you change the value to a string, however, because you're (probably) still using `datetime`, the value `'2019-02-01'` would be interpreted in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`, meaning you get the value `'Wednesday'` (`SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CONVERT(datetime,'2019-02-01'));`), which is the weekday that 02 January 2019 was.

To get the right result, use a non-ambiguous literal string:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190201');
```

Non-ambiguous date(time) formats (regardless of datatype) in SQL Server are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ssss` (The format `yyyy-MM-dd` is non ambiguous **if** you aren't using `datetime`, notice that if you run the following SQL, the value for `datetime` is different:)

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'2019-02-01') AS [date],
       CONVERT(datetime,'2019-02-01') AS [datetime],
       CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2019-02-01') AS [datetime2],
       CONVERT(datetimeoffset,'2019-02-01') AS [datetimeoffset];
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! This was driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use this `datetime` should be in string format(date format)

```
 SELECT GETDATE(), DATENAME(w, GETDATE()),DATENAME(dw, '2019-02-01')
```

output

```
2019-02-01 14:01:38.343          Friday          Friday
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime should be passed in single quotes!

Check :

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = 2019-02-01
SELECT @date
```

Your initial query (without the quotes)  involves an "implied conversion" where your date column is being converted to a varchar (using a server default format for that conversion [That is treated as the default date plus the number of days equal to the computed amount of the assigned value.])

Comment: The value `2019-02-01` isn't being converted to a `varchar` at all. Those are 3 integer values, in an expression, which is being evaluated and then implicitly converted to a `datetime`.